# How to print same category data in same table and different data in different table in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I want to print thease all data group by in same table when cat_id is same for data if cate_id is different create new table and print that's category data
Plz help me

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 5
    [cat_id] => 5
    [title] => Canara Bank Recruitment 2016
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 4
    [cat_id] => 4
    [title] => Canara Bank Recruitment 2016
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 3
    [cat_id] => 3
    [title] => Canara Bank Recruitment 2016
)
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 8
    [cat_id] => 3
    [title] => Canara Bank Recruitment 2016  
)
$current_cat = 0;
foreach ($post as $key => $value)
                {
                        if($current_cat ==0)
                        {   
                            $current_cat = $value->cat_id;
                            echo '<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 75%;margin: auto;">  
                                        <div class="panel-heading">'.$current_cat.'</div>  
                                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                                                <thead> 
                                                    <tr> 
                                                        <th>Title</th> 
                                                    </tr> 
                                                </thead> 
                                                <tbody>';
                        }

                        if($current_cat !=0 && $current_cat!= $value->cat_id)
                        {   
                            echo '</tbody> 
                                    </table> 
                                </div>';
                        }

                        echo '<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 75%;margin: auto;">  
                                        <div class="panel-heading">'.$current_cat.'</div>  
                                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                                                <thead> 
                                                    <tr> 
                                                        <th>Title</th> 
                                                    </tr> 
                                                </thead> 
                                                <tbody>';
                        $current_cat = $value->cat_id;
                        echo '<tr>

                                    <td>'.$value->title.'</td>
                                </tr>';
                    }
                    if($current_cat !=0)
                    {   
                        echo '</tbody> 
                                </table> 
                            </div>';
                    }
```

I have many data in result but i have not mentioned here.
[image: This is output result]

Comment: why you are not using `GROUP BY` clause of MySQL? Use it for column cat_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Query your data ordering by cat_id: `order by cat_id`
2. Declare an $cat varible in php and set its value to empty string (`''`). This will hold the cat_id field to determine whether you need a new table or not.
3. Start your php loop looping through the query results.
4. If $cat is empty, then start a new table and set $cat to the current record's cat_id. If it is not empty, but $cat does not equal to the current record's cat_id, then end the current table, start a new table, set $cat to the current record's cat_id.
5. No matter what the outcome of the previous point is, print the current record into the table.
6. Php loop ends.
7. If $cat is not empty, end table.

UPDATE

1. You do not echo $end anywhere
2. There is an uncnditional echo in the body of the loop that creates table header for every record. That echo should be part of the previous if(), to start a new table if current record's category do nit match the stored one.

Comment: 1. "i am not getting response as i want" is not an informative description of the issue. Describe **specifically** what unexpected behaviour you encounter. 2. What is $post variable? 3. What have you done to debug your code?

Comment: sorry I did correct now data grouping well but header populated again in some cases.

Comment: No, xyu did not correct it. There is still an unconditional echo starting a new table for every record below the 2nd if. As I wrote, that echo should be part of the previous if().